# how to read output of a command run using cmd.exe

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I would like to programatically run following command on command prompt, read its output and then just kill the command window.

> sc query eventlog

When I run this command manually, below is what I get.

[image]

Here is code what I have for it.

```
class Program
    {
        static string output;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "sc query eventlog";
            p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
            p.Start();


            p.BeginOutputReadLine();

            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Kill();
        }

        static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            output += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

However in my case, the it just keep waiting on call for WaitForExit. For that I might have to kill this process. But I see following in the ouput varaible.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]   (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change it so the filename is sc.exe instead of cmd.exe and remove sc from the arguments.

Comment: @MarkPM that was it. How can I answer your comment as answer?

Comment: I've added it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call sc.exe instead of cmd.exe:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "sc.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "query eventlog";
```